# React-Native: How does react-native-webview work under the hood?

Tags: android, windows, react-native, webview

I wanted to know how exactly does webview work under the hood on different platforms (Like Windows, iOS)? I don't even understand what webview is? Is it an independant embeddable browser? Or it uses something like chromium under the hood? Because I've read somewhere that on Android, it uses [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) which is chromium.

Comment: I think your question really is about which engine React Native uses for web views on Windows, right?

Comment: Good point, I've edited the question